# How to display part of the product image over div with gray background color?

Tags: html, css, laravel-blade

I'm trying to design  product details and one of the requirements is to design product image like this 
[https://imgur.com/Q8psgf7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3xJx.jpg)

```
<div class="button-wrap divide-md">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <a href="{{ route('products')  }}" class="productCategories radio-label" id="city1-button">
                 <label class="button-label @if($productCat == 0) chosen_productCategory @endif" for="product1-button">
                     <h1>{{ trans("public.allProducts")  }}</h1>
                  </label>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
      @foreach ($products_cats as $product_cat)
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  <a href="{{ route('products_cat', $product_cat->id) }}" class="productCategories radio-label" id="city1-button">
                       <label class="button-label @if($productCat == $product_cat->id) chosen_productCategory @endif" for="product1-button">
                            <h1>{{ $product_cat->name }}</h1>
                       </label>
                   </a>
               </div>
           </div>
       @endforeach
 </div>
```

I tried using `css` like :
`postion :relative`
`z-index` ....etc 
but couldn't make it.

Comment: Please read about [Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and [Box Shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your rendered HTML and the CSS for this specific image in your markup. There is currently no image at all in your question. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for extra markup, you can use `pseudo` elements for this:

```css
.image-wrap {
  margin: 100px;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  max-width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrap:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10%;
  left: -10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  z-index: -1;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
</div>
```

And using percentages for the `top` and `left` values of the `:before` makes it so the background box always stays relative to the size of the image if it gets smaller or larger due to responsive CSS.

Answer (score 0):

From image attached it seems you want something like following.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.parent div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

div.first {
  background: grey;
}

div.second {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class='first'/>
  <div class="second"/>
</div>
```